# How to bold text using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have variable with text

`let data = "text text 04.02.2018 18:02:82 text text"`

I have regex for catch date like this: `04.02.2018 18:02:82`.

How can I "bold" matchechs?

```
data = data.replace(/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:/g, '<b>$1</b>')
```

Not working, because return `text text <b>$1</b> text text`

What is wrong?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `$&`?

Comment: @Patrickkx Nope. Now it working.

Comment: `.replace(/(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})/g, '<b>$1</b>')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Your Regular Expression has a problem

At the end, you have a colon char

```
data = data.replace(/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:/g, '<b>$1</b>')

                                                                  ^
```

Add the regexp for a single space `\s`

```
data = data.replace(/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:/g, '<b>$1</b>')
                                          ^
```

For matching a dot you need to use the following: `\.`

## Look at this code snippet

*An alternative is passing a callback function to the `replace` function.*

```js
let data = "text text 04.02.2018 18:02:82 text text";

data = data.replace(/\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/g, function(match) {
  return `<b>${match}</b>`;
});

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following approach:

```js
let data = "text text 04.02.2018 18:02:82 text text";
data = data.replace(/(\d{1,2}.){2}\d{4} (\d{1,2}:){2}\d{1,2}/g, '<b>$&</b>');
console.log(data);
```

(One issue: your pattern has trailing `:` in `\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:` - while it shouln't)

Answer (score 2):

```
let data = "text text 04.02.2018 18:02:82 text text";
data = data.replace(/(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})/g, '<b>$1</b>');
```

You have to group the pattern in order to refer to the result as $1